# node-mongodb-native: multiple Db connections for the same replica set?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I've got a replica set holding two different databases: db1 and db2. With node-mongodb-native, how do I access these two databases?

I'm trying to do something like this right now:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var repSet = new mongo.ReplSet( ... );

var conn1 = new mongo.Db('db1', repSet);
var conn2 = new mongo.Db('db2', repSet);
```

But when executing that last line, I get:

```
Failed to open database 'ads'! (Error: in process of connection)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was calling `conn1.open()` and then `conn2.open()`, and the error was getting thrown on that second, `conn2.open()` call. Apparently when re-using a replica set, the connection will already be open. Checking for `conn2.state === 'connected'` did the trick.